# WebView inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, webview, android-recyclerview

I'm having problem loading WebView inside RecyclerView.

While scrolling the WebView goes blank.

I need to tap on the WebView for loading it.

Is there a way this can happen automatically?

Comment: Does it happen when recycling views or everytime you scroll? Have you tried using .notifyDataSetChanged() every time this particular view is bind ? Show some code....

Comment: Entries in the dataset are bounded to a viewholder at the start only.

Dataset also remains same, so notifyDataSetChanged also won't work.

When we scroll, the view gets recycled and the WebView loads very slowly/do not load.

This problem is solved when I do not recycle the viewholer.

But then scrollbar behaves unexpectedly.

Comment: @amanmehara ....have you got the solution?.....i am also facing same issue...

Answer (score 2):

I was having a problem with the outer container of the webview. All views should be `match_parent` for both outer container (parent) and the webview.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/bubble"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/messageUserAvatar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/messageUserAvatar"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/chatWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

otherwise the webview is blank and when you open keyboard for example or refresh the screen the webview appears automatically.

hope this helps